# Img set to max-width: 100% is publishing larger than the actual image size?

Tags: html, css

This is driving me bonkers. In my CSS is this code

```
img {max-width:100%; height:auto; }
```

But when I upload an image to the blog post that is 200x200

```
<img width="200" title="photo-Trent-Dysmid.jpg" style="width: 200px; float: right;" alt="photo-Trent-Dysmid.jpg" src="http://inboundmarketing.digitalhive.buzz/hubfs/jan-2016-images/photo-Trent-Dysmid.jpg" data-constrained="true">
```

And then preview the blog post, it is publishing it at 798x798, basically to the full width of the blog page. The only way I can get it to display at the right size is by manually changing "width: 200px" to "max-width: 200px" but what a drag to have to do that every time! What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Rebekah

Answer (score 6):

`max-width: 100%`

The percentage value will refere to the width of the container the img-element is in, and not the picture itself!

Example:

```
<div style="width: 500px"><img src="..." style="max-width: 100%" /></div>
```

So if the container has a width of 500px, the img-element will have a max-width of 500px as well

---

You could set a custom max-width fitting the image using JavaScript and the image.onload event:

```
<img onload="this.style.maxWidth = this.width + 'px'" src="..." />
```

Comment: By the way, you could set a custom max-width fitting the image using JavaScript and the image.onload event

Comment: I was wondering if that was the case that it is setting it to the container but I can't find any code as to how to get it to set to the image itself. I'm not savvy enough to know how to use JavaScript and image.onload event to set that up. Do you a link that I might look at?

Comment: OK I dropped that into my CSS. Was there also something I needed to upload into a JavaScript file or that's all I need?

Comment: You dont need any CSS. You have to use the onload in the img element